# Reading my own writes in the same (yet uncommitted) transaction

Tags: badgerdb

Is it possible to read my own writes within the same transaction, if that transaction has not yet been committed?

Answer (score -1):

Create a `CacheManager` wrapper atop BadgerDB's read and write transactions to manage an in-memory cache for better consistency:

1. **Initialization**: Set up `CacheManager` with an empty cache, maximum cache size, and a linked BadgerDB instance.
2. **Custom Read**: Implement a read function that checks the in-memory cache first. If the key is cached, return its value; otherwise, read from BadgerDB. This ensures recent data accessibility within transactions.
3. **Custom Write**: Create a write function that updates the cache with new key-value pairs. If the cache exceeds the size limit, initiate a batch flush to store cached entries on disk.
4. **Cache Control**: Monitor cache size during writes. Exceeding the limit triggers a batch flush for memory efficiency and consistent storage.

With `CacheManager`, you seamlessly blend in-memory caching and BadgerDB, enabling read-your-own-writes within transactions while maintaining data coherence and efficiency.